# Keyboard hides after onActivityResult

Tags: android

I am developing chat application. WhenI click **Take picture** button my keyboard appears and the new intent starts. When I take the picture and return to chat application, the keyboard is hidden. I want the keyboard to remain appeared.

Anyone else had this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: That might be happening because focus is getting lost. Can you post your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

To show soft keyboard do this:

```
//Import this
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

//Create object
private InputMethodManager imm;

imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: thanks, can't try it now...will try later. method toggleSoftInput with  show and hide flags is interesting!

Comment: I have tried this inside `onActivityResult()`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to open the keyboard within `onActivityResult()` after getting a picture from Gallery or taking a picture via camera.

To make it works, I have to put a delay like 500 ms. Otherwise, it will not open the keyboard.

Here is my code inside `onActivityResult()`:

```
// Set original file name to description.
EditText etDescription = getView().findViewById(R.id.etAttachmentDescription);
etDescription.setText(fileName);
etDescription.selectAll();
etDescription.requestFocus();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Open keyboard after 500ms
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: This is working. But would like to know why we need to add a delay ? What difference it makes ?

Answer (score 0):

please use this method to hide your soft keyboard .call this method from onactivity result.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity context) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputManager != null)
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getWindow().getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    }
```

Comment: sorry, but I'm not looking to hide a keyboard:) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

@Badrul's solution worked for me but I had to `requestFocus()` on the edit text view first, but it worked great.

```
mEditText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```